# How to Display Different Images in a Row on Mobile and Desktop devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have CSS script that display 4 images in a row.

Here's the results on desktops view:

[image: 4 images in a row]

However, when i switch to mobile i get that result:

[image: 3 images in a row]

How do i set it, so it will display 3 images in a row on mobile? Like that:

[image: 3 images in a row- correctly]

I have try to change the `position` and the `overflow` settings but all i get is the same result- it keeps dragging the 4th square to the bottom at mobile view.

Here's some code:

**HTML:**

```
<div><center>
<ul>
        <li>
            <label for="futurebox08"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
        </li>
         <li>
            <label for="futurebox09"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
        </li>
         <li>
            <label for="futurebox10"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png"  /></a></label>
        </li>
<li>
            <label for="futurebox11"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
        </li>
    </ul>

 <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="futurebox08"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
        </li>
         <li>
            <label for="futurebox09"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
        </li>
         <li>
            <label for="futurebox10"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png"  /></a></label>
        </li>
<li>
            <label for="futurebox11"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
        </li>
    </ul> 
  </center></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  background: black
}

img {
  background-color:white;
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 10%;
}

ul li
    {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 25px 0 0;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
    }

 ul li:hover {  
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px #3aaaf1;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px#3aaaf1;
   box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px #3aaaf1; }

  ul li img, ul li label 
        { 
   display: block; 
   cursor: pointer; 
        }
```

Here's a Live one: **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rami7377/pen/qgEoBr)**

Comment: I would recommend you to work with `display: inline-block` and `max-width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS media queries in order to distinguish between desktop and mobile devices. This will allow you to provide a different set of CSS rules according to the device. In your case 1 set of rules would define each image as 1/3 window width and the other as 1/4 window width in order to allow them to align in a row according to your stated requirements.

Here is a simplified example:

```
/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  img {
    max-width: 30%:
  }
}

/* Dekstop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  img {
    max-width: 25%:
  }
}
```

I don't want to code for you - since media queries are quite important in responsive web design and it would benefit you a whole lot if you take a bit of time to learn them - they're quite simple.

The pixel limit i have put are called "break-points" and they change according to mobile defices, but there are certain standards that usually work. There are tables online for figuring them out.

Here is a good article about media queries:

- https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/

And here is a another good resource *with* break-points / devices tables:

- https://mediag.com/blog/popular-screen-resolutions-designing-for-all/

*Bonus tip:*

I would stop working with absolute pixel size values. There are different relative unit values like vw/vh(window-width/100, window-height/100), %(container width OR height / 100 ) and em and rem which are more flexible and useful for responsive design which supports more display.

Answer (score 0):

@StackBuck` try this code, use media queries and add viewPort to your code here is my codepen link

https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/EraONN

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  background: black
}
img {background-color:white;
  width:150px;
height: 150px;}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
right: 0;
  top: 10%;
}

 ul li
 {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 25px 0 0;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
  ul li:hover {  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px #3aaaf1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px#3aaaf1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px #3aaaf1; }
 
  ul li img, ul li label 
  { 
   display: block; 
   cursor: pointer; 
  }

ul {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  ul {  max-width: 700px; }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">// add viewport to your code

<div><center>
<ul>
        <li>
   <label for="futurebox08"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
  </li>
         <li>
   <label for="futurebox09"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
  </li>
         <li>
   <label for="futurebox10"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png"  /></a></label>
  </li>
<li>
   <label for="futurebox11"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
  </li>
<!--  </ul> -->
 
<!--  <ul> -->
        <li>
   <label for="futurebox08"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
  </li>
         <li>
   <label for="futurebox09"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
  </li>
         <li>
   <label for="futurebox10"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png"  /></a></label>
  </li>
<li>
   <label for="futurebox11"><a href="#" target="new"><img src="https://test.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/testIO-logo-rgb.png" /></a></label>
  </li>
 </ul> 
  </center></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

img src..  is a fallback in case browser doesn't support picture tag:

```
<picture>
   <source 
      media="(min-width: 650px)"
      srcset="images/img1.png">
   <source 
      media="(min-width: 465px)"
      srcset="images/img2.png">
   <img src="images/img-default.png" 
   alt="a cute kitten">
</picture>
```